# AWS Cloudformation - reference tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, aws-cloudformation

I've been looking at moving to CF for some more streamlined infrastructure & code deployment, but I've hit a hurdle. 
I'm looking to deploy web code stored on s3 to a team of iis web servers. I'd like to be able to upgrade the codebase by changing the tag in an auto-scaling group, but I'm unable to find a way to "read" the tag which will be assigned to the ec2 instance for use in AWS::CloudFormation::Init.
The theory here is that we won't have to update the CF everytime we roll a version, or roll-back, just the tag on the auto-scaling group (followed by a scale up and scale down to trigger ec2 instances to rebuild)

i.e. (obviously "Ref" isn't the right way to go here)

```
"sources" : {
  "c:\\inetpub\\wwwroot\\" :  { 
    "Fn::Join" : ["",[{"Ref": "S3_Repo"},{"Ref": "Codebase"},{"Ref":"Version"}, ".zip"  ]]  
  }
},
```

note: static path works fine here, and if I define S3_Repo, Codebase and Version as a Parameter, that also works fine.

Comment: Any reason you're avoiding updating the CloudFormation stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CloudFormation doesn't provide a way to read tags from the EC2 instance - it only allows you to set them.

I would recommend just updating the CloudFormation Stack with new tag values for your Auto Scaling Group, then doing the scale-down and scale up to create new EC2 instances with the updated build (as you suggested in your question).

Changing the "Tags" property of an Auto Scaling Group in CloudFormation won't interrupt operation of the group - see the documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-as-group.html#cfn-as-group-tags) for details.

Comment: That's where I ended up going with this one, The reason why I was avoiding updating the CF-Stack was exactly what you suggested, I feared it pulling the stack down, but my testing last week revealed that was definitely not the case - and changing my deployment script to update the stack variables is working a treat at the moment  - I'll award you the answer as that was the approach I took (although I got there on my own!)